NBGV Code version number is different than main version number
I am switching to using NerdBank Git Versioning (NBGV) package in my .NET core project.  It's working well but I just noticed a discrepancy.  I have my version.json set up to version 9.0 of my software.  Here is the file contents:
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/main/src/NerdBank.GitVersioning/version.schema.json",
  "version": "9.0",
  "assemblyVersion": "9.0",
  "publicReleaseRefSpec": [
    "^refs/heads/master$",
    "^refs/heads/v\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$"
  ],
  "cloudBuild": {
    "buildNumber": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}

When I do this I get an output dll that has what I would expect for a version number.  If I go to properties of the dll file it shows File version: 9.0.17.56274 and Product version: 9.0.17+abcdefg (I'm not in the main branch currently).  All this is what I would expect.
However, when I call typeof(AboutVM).Assembly.GetName().Version?.ToString(); I get back 9.0.0.0.  Why doesn't it show the third value correctly?  I'm trying to show the user what build they have installed based on the version there but that's not going to be correct if it's dropping the third value...
